# how to fix 'Prolem setting TLS options' when running mosquitto_pub to communitate with mosquitto_sub

Tags: mosquitto

here's my mosquitto_pub command

```
mosquitto_pub -h REMOTE_IP -t MSG_TOPIC -m MSG_STRING --cafile /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/ca.crt
```

here's the remove server mosquitto_sub command

```
mosquitto_sub -h localhost -t MSG_TOPIC -i 'myDevice' --cafile /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/ca.pem
```

**mosquitto configuration in the remove server**

```
listener 8883
pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid
persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/
log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log
cafile /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/cert.pem
certfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/chain.pem
keyfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/privkey.pem
persistence_file mosquitto.db
```

Comment: Edit the question to show the actual error. As it is it's not clear if the error is coming from mosquitto or the clients.

Comment: Also describe your environment, what OS and what version of mosquitto are you using